# Display meaning of a word from wiki to ourjsp pages

Tags: java, jsp

How can i read the meaning's and sentences for a words in wiki and has to display in my jsp page dynamically..?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to have an interface to read data from Wikipedia.
You can use one of the following free APIs:

`http://code.google.com/p/jwpl/

http://dbpedia.org/`

Once your server interface is established then you can call your server methods to fetch the data through `AJAX` or some other way of disaplying data on `mouse over` from the JSP page.

You can also directly call Wikipedia from JSP page by `AJAX` but I would suggest to use your own server method to fetch the data so in future if you have to apply some filter to censor the content then it will easier to implement.

Comment: DatabaseConfiguration dbConfig = new DatabaseConfiguration();
        dbConfig.setHost("SERVER_URL");
        dbConfig.setDatabase("DATABASE");
        dbConfig.setUser("USER");
        dbConfig.setPassword("PASSWORD");
        dbConfig.setLanguage(Language.german);
WHER TO GET THERS USER NAMES , PASSWORDS..?

Comment: You will have to create a database using the scripts provided.  Please see the full documentation at: http://code.google.com/p/jwpl/wiki/JWPLDocumentation